# How to create azure pipeline for soapui xml file (bitbucket)

Tags: azure-devops, soapui

I am new in azure integration with bitbucket for soapui project.
My requirement is : how to create pipeline and run in azure devops for soapui xml ?

I have tried to create pipeline in azure devops and added empty job after that I added task (soapui for azure)
And publish test result . I am getting 233 error and test tab is not appearing in build